# Bootstrap Datepicker plugin not working with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

Here is the html code I am using:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" data-ng-model="dateOfCal" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works on index.html, but when I move this code to an html page that is accessed by

```
<div ng-view=''></div>
```

the calendar no longer pops up.

Comment: you could use [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which is an Angular wrapper for Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your jquery code to the controller that is loading the ng-view. It will work for sure.

Just make sure that you have included your jquery above angular

**Suggestion** You can use ui-bootstrap (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which has built in angular JS directive for datepicker and a lot more things that you can use in your project

Comment: are you saying to put the jquery in the controller instead of a file that is referenced?

Answer (score 0):

try this one may be it will help you,

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Birth Date</label>
    <p class="input-group">
    <input type= "text" class="form-control" placeholder="MMM DD,YYYY" ng-model="birthDate" datepicker-popup="MMM dd,yyyy"
                             is-open="birthDatePicker.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="birthDatePicker.toggle()">
                             <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </button>
    </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.birthDatePicker = {
     opened: false,
     toggle: function () {
     this.opened = !this.opened;
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code is not working because `ready` event not triggered after loading the view**

Please write this code `$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();` at the last line inside controller so that datepicker will be initialize.